# Why button doesn't align properly using default layout?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3

I can't align my button under `form-group` which consist of `label` and `input`. It always align beside between `label` and `input`. See screenshot below.

Screenshot

[image: SC]

```
<div class = "row">

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li><a href = "#">Create Department</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#">Manage</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class = "col-md-12">

        <br>
        <form class = "form-vertical" role = "form">

            <div class = "form-group col-xs-5">

                <label for = "department" class = "control-label">Department Name:</label>                  <input type= "text" name = "department" class = "form-control">

            </div>

            <div class = "form-group">

                <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary">Create</button>

            </div>

        </form>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: col-xs-5 remove this class

Comment: If the answer is helpful for you, just accept it.

Answer (score 0):

They are on the same row because you have specified `col-xs-5` on the first `form-group`. Try removing that things should work.

Answer (score 0):

you can rewrite ur html like this

```
<form class = "form-vertical" role = "form">

        <div class = "form-group">

            <label for = "department" class = "control-label">Department Name:</label>                  <input type= "text" name = "department" class = "form-control">

        </div>

        <div class = "form-group">

            <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary">Create</button>

        </div>

    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to solve your current problem only try this code please.

```
<div class = "row">

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li><a href = "#">Create Department</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#">Manage</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class = "col-md-12">

        <br>
        <form class = "form-vertical" role = "form">
<div class="row">
            <div class = "form-group col-xs-5">
            <label for = "department" class = "control-label">
             Department Name:</label><input type= "text" name = "department" class = "form-control">

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class = "form-group">

                <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary">Create</button>

            </div>
          </row>
        </form>

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take your button under the form then you have to create another row like this thought:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-5">
        // Label
        // Input form
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-5">
        // Button
   </div>
</div>
```

If you use row, then content will take place beside the wall, but if you use `col-xs-12` against `row` then it will create some space. By your code:

```
<div class = "row">

            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li>
                    <a href = "#">Create Department</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href = "#">Manage</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <div class = "col-md-12">

                <br>
                <form class = "form-vertical" role = "form">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class = "form-group col-xs-5">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <label for = "department" class = "control-label">Department Name:</label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <input type= "text" name = "department" class = "form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12">

                        <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary">
                            Create
                        </button>

                    </div>

            </div>
            </form>

        </div>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the label out side the the option group like,

```
<div class = "row">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href = "#">Create Department</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#">Manage</a></li>
</ul>
<div class = "col-md-12">
    <br>
    <form class = "form-vertical" role = "form">
        <div class = "col-md-12">
             <label for = "department" class = "control-label">Department Name:</label>                  
        </div>
        <div class = "form-group col-xs-5">
            <input type= "text" name = "department" class = "form-control">
        </div>
        <div class = "form-group">              
            <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary">Create</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**[JSFiddile](https://jsfiddle.net/vinodvt22/Leybu8xz/1/)**

Answer (score -1):

You have to create 2 more div, one for text and one for button.

Please try below html.

If you want to put Create button next to html then try below code.

```
<div class = "row">

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li><a href = "#">Create Department</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#">Manage</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class = "col-md-12">
    <br/>
      <form class = "form-vertical" role = "form">
      <div class = "col-md-12">
        <label for = "department" class = "control-label">Department Name:</label>
      </div>
      <div class = "form-group col-xs-5">
        <input type= "text" name = "department" class = "form-control">
      </div>
      <div class = "form-group">
        <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary">Create</button>
      </div>
  </form>
</div>

</div>
```

Or If you want to put Create button after text then.

```
<div class = "row">

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href = "#">Create Department</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#">Manage</a></li>
</ul>

<div class = "col-md-12">
<br/>
  <form class = "form-vertical" role = "form">
  <div class = "col-md-12">
    <label for = "department" class = "control-label">Department Name:</label>
  </div>
  <div class = "form-group">
    <input type= "text" name = "department" class = "form-control">
  </div>
  <div class = "form-group">
    <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary">Create</button>
  </div>
```